# JavaScript Image (how to set height and width, using document.getElementById().src=' ')

Tags: javascript

How do I set the Bush picture to 100px by 100px?

```
<!DOCTYE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Title </title>
        <script>

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button type = button onclick = "document.getElementById('myImage').src='bush.jpg'">Bush</button>
        <button type = button onclick = "document.getElementById('myImage').src='obama.jpg'">Obama</button>
        <p>Default is Obama </p>
        <img id = "myImage" src = "obama.jpg" style = "width: 100px;  height: 100px">
    </body>
</html>
```

I am in the beginning phase of learning javascript. Not sure what other information is really needed. I'm just trying to get a job in full-stack web development and realized there's less jobs in what I learned in school (Java/C/C++). I know it's a relatively simple question but don't know how to google the answer either since I don't know how to phrase the question... ha... anyone with some decent experience know how to do this?

Comment: You missed a semicolon after `width: 100px`

Answer (score 0):

Your style attribute is has invalid information in it. Your image tag looks like this:

```
<img id = "myImage" src = "obama.jpg" style = "width: 100px height: 100px">
```

and it should look like this:

```
<img id = "myImage" src = "obama.jpg" style = "width: 100px; height: 100px;">
```

Notice the added `;`

Here is an example of setting style on the image dynamically. I used a function to switch the images.

```html
<button type = button onclick = "changeImage('bush');">Bush</button>
<button type = button onclick = "changeImage('obama')">Obama</button>
<p>Default is Obama </p>
<img id = "myImage" src = "https://whitehouse.gov1.info/photos_obama_face/obama-happy-flag.jpg" style = "width: 100px;  height: 100px" />

<script>
function changeImage(chump) {
    var img = document.getElementById('myImage');

    if(chump === 'obama') {
        img.src = 'https://whitehouse.gov1.info/photos_obama_face/obama-happy-flag.jpg';
        img.style.width = '100px';
        img.style.height = '100px';
    }
    else {
        img.src = 'http://www.capitolhillblue.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/071511bush.jpg';
        img.style.width = '200px';
        img.style.height = '200px';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks - what about changing Bush (the button) to 200x200?

Comment: @Gary - maybe you should study alone before you ask every single thing you don't know how to do.

Comment: @Gary If this fixed your problem would you mind accepting the answer?